# Sql How to check if value before nulls is the same as after nulls Window functions

Tags: sql

I have a table with a column x that has many rendom values like so:

```
7
null
null
4
null
null
null
4
```

I need to check whether the number before the `NULL`s is the same as the number after the `NULL`s and if so, convert `NULL` to that number. If it isn't, the `NULL` remains. So the result would be another column with values like this:

```
7
null
null
4
4
4
4
4
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: First you need  a column to determine order.

Comment: Please tag your question with the RDBMS that you are using : oracle, mysql, sql-server, ...?

Answer (score 0):

Using windowed functions:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT t.*, SUM(CASE WHEN val IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS grp
  FROM t
)
SELECT c1.id, c1.val,
      CASE WHEN c2.val = MIN(c1.val) OVER(PARTITION BY c1.grp)
          THEN c2.val
          ELSE c1.val
      END AS filled_val
FROM cte c1
LEFT JOIN cte c2
  ON c1.grp = c2.grp-1
  AND c2.val IS NOT NULL;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=324ae8d615cee528a2a2611c96e3c23f)**

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that you have a unique column to sort the values, called `id` (without such a colum, your question just cannot be solved).

If you are using a RDBMS that supports option `IGNORE NULLS` in window functions (such as Oracle), you can proceed as follows :

```
SELECT id, CASE WHEN val IS NULL AND lg = ld THEN lg ELSE val END val
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id,
        val,
        LAG(val IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY id) lg,
        LEAD(val IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY id) ld
     FROM t
) x
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9c36cb939b8165ecc61bd27f5ca97f72)** :

```
ID |  VAL
-: | ---:
 1 |    7
 2 | null
 3 | null
 4 |    4
 5 |    4
 6 |    4
 7 |    4
 8 |    4
```

---

On a RDBMS that does not support window functions (such as MySQL < 8.0), you can take the quite inefficient but safe option of using `JOIN`s with correlated subqueries to locate the preceeding and next record where the value is not null :

```
SELECT t1.id, CASE WHEN t0.val = t2.val THEN t0.val ELSE t1.val END val
FROM t t1
LEFT JOIN t t0
    ON  t1.val IS NULL 
    AND t0.val IS NOT NULL
    AND t0.id < t1.id 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t WHERE val IS NOT NULL AND id < t1.id AND id > t0.id)
LEFT JOIN t t2
    ON  t1.val IS NULL 
    AND t2.val IS NOT NULL
    AND t2.id > t1.id 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t WHERE val IS NOT NULL AND id > t1.id AND id < t2.id)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c8cf81baa5cba2186c1543309907683f)**.